# Will php documentation conflict with wordpress documentation?

Tags: documentation

Hi I have a php script that makes liberal use of

> `/* */`
>
> `//`

my question is will that conflict with wordpress since the wordpress engine often reads variables inside those things?

The reason I ask is that to make a custom template, you just modify some text inside the documentation in the first part of the script

/**
 * Template Name: Full Width Page
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */

I worry my documentation inside my script could cause wordpress to do unexpected actions or worse create a security vulnerability

Comment: You need WAY more detail in your question. Please elaborate.

Comment: WordPress is written in PHP, it's not a fork or alternative to PHP. it doesn't do any PHP file parsing as your question suggests

Comment: I updated it, i mean wordpress does read inside the annotation and documentation right, otherwise how would they see the template name etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the practice of including additional data within PHP code comments is typically called *annotations*.

WordPress core makes no use of annotations technique for any code runtime tasks and doesn't have an API for such purpose.

In number of context it *will* read file headers to extract meta data, such as main plugin files and some theme templates. As long as you follow documentation and include necessary elements for those I doubt you are going to have any trouble with them.

Comment: this is mostly correct but have few exceptions relating to plugin and page template headers

Comment: Hm hm... You are right, but I am not confident is that falls within "annotations" ? I think it's commonly associated with more technical stuff like controlling dependency injection. I'll amend the answer anyway.

Comment: Probably the original was correct for what the OP asks, but people might get wrong impression that they can put "whatever" everywhere

Comment: okay thanks, so as long as the annotations/documentation isn't in the first part of the template plugin files, i should be okay right?

Comment: @johndoe yes, outside of file headers you are completely fine :) I am also pretty sure you are unlikely to introduce any security issues since headers WP cares about should be whitelisted and escaped for output.